# How to disable loggers from other modules?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I use several modules in my project, however, the modules output lots of logs from the logger, which is annoying. So I turn off the logs by:

```
boto_log = logging.getLogger("boto")
boto_log.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
es_log = logging.getLogger("elasticsearch")
es_log.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
urllib3_log = logging.getLogger("urllib3")
urllib3_log.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```

Though this works, the code looks verbose. Is there any better, simpler way I can do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can disable existing loggers with either `logging.config.dictConfig` or `logging.config.fileConfig`.

```
import logging.config
logging.config.dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    # Other configs ...
    'disable_existing_loggers': True
})
```

You can also loop over existing loggers and disable manually.

```
for name, logger in logging.root.manager.loggerDict.iteritems():
    logger.disabled=True
```

Answer (score 17):

May be you can refactor it in order to cut some of the boilerplate:

```
for _ in ("boto", "elasticsearch", "urllib3"):
    logging.getLogger(_).setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```

Comment: So I still need to iterate all the modules which uses loggers by myself?

Comment: Someone may came up with a better way, but at least this is not so verbose. I would say "explicit is better than implicit", so I don't think it is a bad idea to explicitly disable the logs I want to disable (instead of doing it automatically and losing some important message because of that). Looks like a good compromise between clarity and ease of use.

Comment: "explicit is better than implicit" I agree with this:)

Answer (score 9):

You can get a list of all loggers (excluding the root logger) from `logging.root.manager.loggerDict`.

```
for _ in logging.root.manager.loggerDict:
    logging.getLogger(_).setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
    # logging.getLogger(_).disabled = True  # or use this instead of CRITICAL if you'd rather completely disable it
```

This allows you the flexibility to put in your own filter etc if you'd rather actually keep some loggers.

Answer (score 1):

You should know exactly name of logger which you want to disable. `"urllib3.connectionpool" != "urllib3"`.

```
logging.getLogger("boto").disabled = True
logging.getLogger("elasticsearch").disabled = True
logging.getLogger("urllib3").disabled = True
logging.getLogger('urllib3.connectionpool').disabled = True
```