# How to prevent imported packages/modules from adding logging handlers

Tags: python, logging

Context: I would like to create a single stream to stdout of log events formatted in JSON without any duplicate events. Within my own applications, this is relatively simple. I simply configure the root logger to have a single `StreamHandler` and use python-json-logger as the `Formatter`.

```py
included_attributes = '%(asctime)s %(filename)s %(funcName)s %(lineno)d %(message)s %(levelname)s %(module)s %(name)s %(pathname)s %(process)d %(thread)s %(threadName)s'
json_formatter = jsonlogger.JsonFormatter(included_attributes)

def change_root_logger_format():
    root_logger = logging.getLogger()
    root_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    root_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    root_handler.setFormatter(json_formatter)
    root_logger.handlers = [root_handler]
```

For various modules I add the standard `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`.

All logs roll up the hierarchy to root with my single `StreamHandler()` and output to stdout as JSON.

As I understand it, best practice for distributed packages is that they don't declare their own handlers (or at least check if they are `__main__` before doing so). I have found that this is not universally applied, however.

I am using at least one package that adds its own handlers. That is, the package `__init__.py` contains something like

```py
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(StreamHandler())
```

As a result, I end up with duplicate logs for everything logged by this package. One line from its own handler, and one from the root logger.

The only solution I've found to this is to remove the handlers after the fact. That is, loop through `logging.root.manager.loggerDict` and removing the handlers of any `Logger` that isn't `root`. The problem with this approach is that any new import could cause new `Handlers` to appear. Thus, all of my modules would need the same boilerplate handler removal after their imports.

Does anyone know of a way to prevent this problem pre-emptively and exhuastively? That is, preventing all loggers but root from having `Handlers`?

I don't believe this question is a duplicate. There are many questions on *disabling* package/module loggers (for example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27538879/how-to-disable-loggers-from-other-modules)). These questions and answers don't apply to removing handlers while keeping the logger active.

Comment: I don't think there is a way, other than what you have outlined. You could help to make things better by logging an issue with the maintainers of the libraries concerned, expaining that what they are doing is a pattern to avoid - https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#patterns-to-avoid

Comment: @VinaySajip I thought this might be the case. Thanks for the reference, I will raise the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable logging from imported modules using the logging module. You can configure it to not log messages unless they are at least warnings using the following code: import logging logging.getLogger("imported_module").setLevel(logging.WARNING)

Comment: That won't work. The OP doesn't want to prevent messages from those modules - just to not have them appear twice.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).